# How do i format a decimal with dot notation

Tags: apex, visualforce

I tried:

```
<apex:outputtext value="{0, number, #.####}">
       <apex:param value="{!TotalE}">
       </apex:param>
```

This gives me only a number without decimals. I would like to format for example

> `234789.00` to `234.789`

so no decimals and thousands separated by.

Comment: Got it so simple 'apex:outputtext value="{0, number, #.####}">
                <apex:param value="{!TotalE/1000}"></apex:param>
    </apex:outputtext>'

Answer (score 2):

Use `{0, Number, #,###,###,##0.00}` as your formula on the `outputText` tag.

Comment: your solution gives me 386,258.00 my question was to achieve for example 123.386.258,00

Comment: Then try using just `{0, Number, 0.00}`?

Comment: this is the american style of writing numbers like 368,258,456,895 what I want to achieve is the swedisch style which is 368.258.456.895 so the thousand separetor has to be a dot and not a comma